# 2 INNER JOINs in one SELECT statement

Tags: sql, database, select, inner-join

I've got three tables in my database: stockitem, supplier and city.

I need to run an SQL query that selects the stock id (`stkid`), stock name (`stkname`) and the relative city name of the stock id's supplier (linked with `suppid`).

In order to do this, I've been told I'll need to run 2 `INNER JOIN` statements that should link the two `suppid` attributes from the stockitem table (foreign key) and supplier table (primary key).

Likewise, I need to do the same with the `citycode` in both the table supplier (FK) and city (PK).

Here's what I have:

```
SELECT      I.stkid     ,   I.stkname   ,   C.cityname "Supplier Location"
FROM        stockitem I

-- inner join stockitem <-> supplier
INNER JOIN  supplier S 
ON          I.suppid = S.suppid

-- inner join supplier <-> city
INNER JOIN  city C
ON          S.citycode = C.citycode

ORDER BY    stkid ASC;
```

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks!!

EDIT: Sorry, completely forgot to send the output. Here's the error I keep getting.

```
SELECT      I.stkid     ,   I.stkname   ,   C.cityname "Supplier Location"
                                *
Error at line 1:
ORA-00904: "C"."CITYNAME": invalid identifier

INNER JOIN  supplier S 
*
Error at line 1:
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

INNER JOIN  city C
*
Error at line 1:
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

I was expecting simply all my stockitem rows to be returned with their relative attributes, `stkid`, `stkname` and the `cityname` that was referenced from the city table (via the supplier table).

Comment: What is your question? What is the problem with the query you posted?

Comment: And what's wrong with the select? Do you get an error? Wrong result? If you get a wrong result, what is what you expect?

Comment: what's problem regarding your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Oracle treat your query like 3 distincted queries.
Try to eliminate blank lines and similar.

If it doesn't work, you can just use implicit inner join, like

```
SELECT      I.stkid     ,   I.stkname   ,   C.cityname "Supplier Location"
FROM        stockitem I, supplier S , city C
where     I.suppid = S.suppid and   S.citycode = C.citycode
ORDER BY    stkid ASC;
```

Comment: I just removed the comments and blank lines and it worked great... Had no idea that blank lines/comments impacted the query. Thanks for your help!!!